# Matrix form of 2D-DFT for a vectorized image

Tags: dft

I want to apply 2d DFT to a N by N image. However, image is vectorized such that it is NxN by 1. How can i find the matrix form of 2d DFT such that resulting vector from multiplication is the vectorized NxN by 1 2d DFT of my N by N image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In matrix form, we can write the 2-D DFT of an Image $\mathbf X$ via $\hat{\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf F \mathbf X \mathbf F^{\rm T}$.

This expression can be vectorized with the help of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Using [[*]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations), we obtain $$\hat{{\mathbf{x}}} = {\rm vec}\{\hat{\mathbf{X}}\} = (\mathbf F \otimes \mathbf F) \cdot \mathbf{x}.$$

This shows that the matrix you need is $\mathbf F \otimes \mathbf F$.

Comment: thank you very much. Works like a charm! I cannot upvote due to my reputation though :/ Have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear it helped. You should be able to accept it as an answer though. ;-)

Comment: how about the inverse 2D-DFT?

Comment: @mlbj: it would be quite similar, you would only need to replace $\mathbf F$ by its complex conjugate (and adjust for the scaling, depending on your preferred scaling convention), since $\mathbf F \mathbf F^{\rm H}$ is a scaled identity if $^{\rm H}$ denotes the conjugate (Hermitian) transpose.

Comment: thank you very much!